# Removing system tray notifications

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, notifications

Using Windows 7, I am running WhatPulse. It generates annoying notifications in the system tray that I just don't need to see. The administrator on WhatPulse forums refuses to accept there is a problem.

I prefer the option "Always show all icons and notifications on the taskbar", as I don't want programs that are running to be hidden. However, I don't want to see any notifications at all, although suppression of notifications would be handy for specific icons.

I can't select to not see notifications, but be able to see the icon. That's the biggest gripe. I want the icon so I can right click it to open it up, but the annoying notifications are useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can disable all notifications with Local Group Policy Editor

1. Launch **gpedit.msc**
2. Go to `User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Start Menu and Taskbar`
3. Enable `Turn off feature advertisement balloon notifications`, and as you wish `Turn off all balloon notifications`

Note that if you turn off all notifications and your password is set to expire, you will miss the notification before it expire, then you cannot login anymore until a password reset.
You can fix it using a script to check on login if your password expires soon.

[image: Turn off feature advertisement balloon notifications]

[image: Turn off all balloon notification]

Comment: Thanks. How does Windows tell if a notification is a feature advert? I can't think of a situation where I needed notifications, but it's best not to turn them all off if it's not necessary.

Comment: I guess it's based at application level that tells to the Windows API if the notification is an advertisement or not. So if the developper doesn't specifies if the notification is an advertisement even if it is, you have to turn off all notifications to disable it.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.

**Either** not set it to show all icons, and set all but that specific program to show all icons and notifications, **or** find a replacement program for WhatPulse that does the same except for these notifications.